# Using for loops (with Tuples in them) to populate a Tuple array

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, tuples, nested-loops

So I'm making a card game and I need an array with 3 strings and a bool in it for each card and when I run the programme it creates two instances of Aces for each Suit and I don't why, probably missing something really obvious but I have no clue why it's doing that.

class Deck
    {

```
    Tuple<string, string, string, bool>[] DeckArray = new Tuple<string, string, string, bool>[56];


    public void DeckArrayAssigner()
    {
        string Number, Suit, Card;
        int Count = 0;
        int A = 1;
        int B = 1;

        for (Tuple<int, int> Assigner = new Tuple<int, int>(A, B); Assigner.Item2 <= 3; Assigner = new Tuple<int, int>(A, B++))
        {
            for (Assigner = new Tuple<int, int>(A, B); Assigner.Item1 <= 13; Assigner = new Tuple<int, int>(A++, B))
            {
                Number = NumericNumberSwitch(Assigner.Item1);
                Suit = NumericSuitSwitch(Assigner.Item2);
                Card = (Number + " of " + Suit);
                DeckArray[Count] = new Tuple<string, string, string, bool>(Number, Suit, Card, true);
                Count++;
                Console.WriteLine(Card);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Assigner = new Tuple<int, int>(A = 1, B);
        }
    }

    public string NumericNumberSwitch(int NumericNumber)
    {
        string Number;
        switch (NumericNumber)
        {
            case 1: Number = "Ace"; break;
            case 2: Number = "Two"; break;
            case 3: Number = "Three"; break;
            case 4: Number = "Four"; break;
            case 5: Number = "Five"; break;
            case 6: Number = "Six"; break;
            case 7: Number = "Seven"; break;
            case 8: Number = "Eight"; break;
            case 9: Number = "Nine"; break;
            case 10: Number = "Ten"; break;
            case 11: Number = "Jack"; break;
            case 12: Number = "Queen"; break;
            case 13: Number = "King"; break;
            default: Number = "???"; break;
        }
        return Number;
    }

    public string NumericSuitSwitch(int NumericSuit)
    {
        string Suit;
        switch (NumericSuit)
        {
            case 1: Suit = "Hearts"; break;
            case 2: Suit = "Diamonds"; break;
            case 3: Suit = "Clubs"; break;
            case 4: Suit = "Spades"; break;
            default: Suit = "???"; break;
        }
        return Suit;
    }
}
```

Output is as follows:

```
Ace of Hearts
Ace of Hearts
Two of Hearts
Three of Hearts
Four of Hearts
Five of Hearts
Six of Hearts
Seven of Hearts
Eight of Hearts
Nine of Hearts
Ten of Hearts
Jack of Hearts
Queen of Hearts
King of Hearts

Ace of Diamonds
Ace of Diamonds
Two of Diamonds
Three of Diamonds
Four of Diamonds
Five of Diamonds
Six of Diamonds
Seven of Diamonds
Eight of Diamonds
Nine of Diamonds
Ten of Diamonds
Jack of Diamonds
Queen of Diamonds
King of Diamonds

Ace of Clubs
Ace of Clubs
Two of Clubs
Three of Clubs
Four of Clubs
Five of Clubs
Six of Clubs
Seven of Clubs
Eight of Clubs
Nine of Clubs
Ten of Clubs
Jack of Clubs
Queen of Clubs
King of Clubs

Ace of Spades
Ace of Spades
Two of Spades
Three of Spades
Four of Spades
Five of Spades
Six of Spades
Seven of Spades
Eight of Spades
Nine of Spades
Ten of Spades
Jack of Spades
Queen of Spades
King of Spades
```

Comment: I recommend you seriously limit the use of `Tuple`.  For the loops on `A` and `B` they just make it overly complicated.  For the other `Tuple`, I'd suggest creating a custom class to hold that information.

Comment: This would be much simpler if you made two lists<String> with the suits in one and the values in the other.  Then have two nested foreach loops.

Comment: Your issue is that you use a post increment on the inner loop, so `A = 1` then you do `A++` which assigns 2 to `A`, but returns 1, the value before the increment.  You don't have the problem with `B` because you reassign it to the `Tuple` at the end of the outer loop.  Really all you need is `for(int A = 1; A <= 3; A++) for(int B = 1; B <= 13; b++)` and just use `A` and `B` instead of all the `Tuple` junk.

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your code a lot by replacing `switch` statements with arrays, dropping unnecessary use of tuples in your loops, and running simple loops to iterate the arrays:

```
static readonly string[] Ranks = new[] {"Ace", "Two", ..., "King"};
static readonly string[] Suits = new[] {"Hearts", ..., "Spades"};
...
int pos = 0;
foreach (rank in Ranks) {
    foreach (suit in Suits) {
        DeckArray[pos++] = Tuple.Create(rank, suit, $"{rank} of {suit}", true);
    }
}
```

**Note:** You would be much better off creating a `class Card` for the individual cards, because `card.Rank` and `card.Suit` read a lot better than `card.Item1` and `card.Item2`.

Comment: `Note: You would be much better off creating a class Card for the individual cards, because card.Rank and card.Suit read a lot better than card.Item1 and card.Item2.` shhh. We don't want pretty code around here.